# Reading an Xml file into map

Tags: java, xml, hashmap

I have an xml string in the following format

```
<map>
  <entry>
    <string>key</string>
    <string>value</string>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <string>key2</string>
    <string>value2</string>
  </entry>
....
</map>
```

Is there an easy library/tool that I can use to read this type of xml directly into a Hashmap. I am not very familiar with working with xml, so I would really appreciate some help here.

Thanks.

Comment: Look into Java SAX parser. It's a bit complex but if you check out some demos I'm sure you can get the hang of it. 

Some references:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html and  
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_sax_parser.htm

Comment: Check this library: https://github.com/miness/xml-lib

Comment: Might try using XStream . You may use      NamedMapConverter namedMapConverter = new NamedMapConverter(xstream.getMapper(),"entry","key",String.class,"value",String.class);